# Looking for proportionality scale in diversity of a demographic

Tags: visualization

I am an amateur on this so please bear with me.

**A little background:**

I live in a country where, let's say, 70% of the population live in the westernmost part of the country, 20% in the middle, and 10% in the easternmost part.

This means that if we are to visualize my country population with Likert scale by using the number of population from the westernmost to the easternmost provinces/states in my country, it will always be heavier on the left side.

I was given a task to create and visualize a scale that explains whether the population within the faculties my campus is proportional to the demographic of my country as a whole. How can I do this?

I had the idea to create a scale chart similar to Likert scale where on the leftmost part shows that it has western population bias, the middle is proportional, and the rightmost part has eastern population bias.

[image]

This means that the value 0 represents perfect diversity proportionality, -1 represents westernmost bias, and +1 represents easternmost bias. However I am uncertain on how I can count this.

**Question:**

Has anybody worked with this kind of data before? Mind sharing me the solution?

Thanks in advance!